Snowflake UDF Unsupported Sub Query Error
I have a Snowflake UDF as mentioned below, when I pass Variable to calculate datediff in line AND DATEDIFF(DAY,STARTDATE, sp.policy_end_date) BETWEEN -30 AND 30 I am getting error UnSupported SubQuery Error
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_EARLY_RENEWAL_DIFF_QUOTE("CONTACTID" NUMBER(38,0), "STARTDATE" TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))
RETURNS NUMBER(38,0)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
SELECT COUNT(t.id)
FROM t_policy t
LEFT JOIN t_quote q ON q.id = t.id
LEFT JOIN t_quote_product sp ON sp.quote_id = t.id
WHERE sp.policy_type = ''ANNUAL_MULTI_TRIP''
  AND DATEDIFF(DAY,STARTDATE, sp.policy_end_date) BETWEEN -30 AND 30
  AND q.individual_contact_id = CONTACTID
  AND t.insurance_status = ''APPROVED''
';

I tried many ways to solve but all try's went in vain, please anyone help

Please update your question with complete SQL statement where you are calling this UDF

it is because you are using rows from a table, as input to the function. Given Snowflake does not do "row based logic" like trivial RMDBs, you need to express what you are trying to do as a real JOIN or an aggregate function

I wonder if having a materialized view of the joins there would help - but we would need more context, sample data, to know if it's feasible

Please could you update your question with minimal ddl (i.e. we only need the columns used in your query, if that's easier than the full table) and sample data for the tables referenced in your function - so we can re-create your function and test it? Thanks
